# Excel (Googel Sheets) formula to find value within range prior to current row only

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, conditional-statements, vlookup

```
  A|B|C|D|E  
------------------------------------  
#|Splr|Payment|Total|Bill|Balance  
------------------------------------  
1|S1|10,000|10,000| 8,000|2,000  
2|S1|12,000|14,000|15,000|-1,000  
3|S2|10,000|10,000| 9,500|500  
4|S1| 9,000| 8,000| 7,500|500  
5|S2| 8,000| 8,500| 6,500|2,000  

B       Current Payment     
C       B + E (of same supplier (last record in previous rows if any))  
D       Current Bill        
E       Total Bill
```

I am searching for a formula (E part of formula in column C) to find the last balance of current supplier up to current row

---

EDIT: After implementing your provided formula (with minor modification), I am facing #Ref issues for every new supplier.
The formula I have used on row #2 (ie first data row) is "=ArrayFormula(IF(ISNUMBER(INDEX($F1:F$2,MAX(IF(A2=$A1:A$2,ROW($A1:A$2)-1,0)))),$F1,0))" 
while on second row and onward it is "=ArrayFormula(IF(ISNUMBER(INDEX($F$2:F2,MAX(IF(A3=$A$2:A2,ROW($A$2:A2)-1,0)))),$F2,0))" where $F1 is replaced by $F$Row# and $A1 is replaced by $A$RowNo

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following formula, will lookup the supplier of the current row, look through all the previous rows with the same supplier, lowest row (previous to the current row) with the same supplier , and then return the balance (value from column E)

In this example, the formula would go in the 6th row of data, or the 7th row on the spreadsheet after accounting for table headers.

This is also an array formula, meaning you have to paste it into the cell, and then hit `ctrl+shift+enter` to submit the formula.

```
=INDEX($E$2:E6,MAX(IF(A7=$A$2:A6,ROW($A$2:A6)-1,0)))
```

You could then copy and paste that cell down your table.

Comment: Thanks for reply. However I am still facing some problems.

Comment: I have updated the question with screen shot and little more description.

Comment: It is giving the error, beacuse you are trying to index -1, which doesn't exist. In excel you can just add an `IFERROR` statement to make `{=IFERROR(INDEX($E$2:E6,MAX(IF(A7=$A$2:A6,ROW($A$2:A6),0))-1),0)}`, That means if there is no earlier entry of the supplier the formula will assume they have a balence of $0. I believe google docs has a similar syntax. `=IFERROR( [insert working formula] , 0)` should produce the desired behavior.

Comment: Thanks @Christopher for your help, but unfortunately it has not solved my problem.

Comment: Fortunately I have solved my problem using INDIRECT(). The formula I have used is {=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(INDIRECT("A2:A"&ROW()-1)=A7),INDIRECT("E2:E"&ROW()-1)),0))}

Comment: This is correct answer and I understand this today.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately I have solved my problem using INDIRECT(). The formula I have used is {=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(INDIRECT("A2:A"&ROW()-1)=A7),INDIRECT("E2:E"&ROW()-1)),0))}

Here INDIRECT() is used to force the criteria range upto previous row of current cell.